# Format numeric string in decimal

Tags: java, decimal

I've requested a API and received a dollar quotation coming that way `0000045717472`

My Java code is here

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject json = (JsonObject) parser.parse(response.toString());
JsonElement dolarDia = json.get("Dolar");

data.put("dataResponse", dolarDia);

return data;
```

How can I perform a way to convert this to a real based currency format: `4.57`?

Comment: is it always going to be `x.xx` not `xx.xx` ? How would say `0000045717472` to be `4.57` and not `45.72` ?

Comment: Yes, is it always have to be x.xx.

Comment: Do you ever get values less than one dollar?  Does the response always have 6 digits and 7 fractional digits?

Comment: the response always have 6 digits and 7 fractionals, yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to process the input on own something similar as below, which include converting input to numeric, since number is too long use `Long`.

```
Long lAmount = Long.parseLong("0000045717472");
```

and then fraction them according to till the number you want. And then format the decimal value with the help of `DecimalFormat`

```
double fraction = Math.pow(10,7);
String format = decimalFormat.format(lAmount/fraction); // print 4.57
```